# Add class to a div if another div has specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, addclass

Add class to a div `.thisdiv` if another div `.textdiv` has specific text `[mytext]`. Example below:

```
<div class="textdiv">
  <div class="here">
  [mytext]
 </div>
</div>
```

Then add class `mytext`:

```
<div class="thisdiv mytext"> </div> /*Add New class .mytext*/
```

I mean, add class to `.thisdiv` if only `<div class="textdiv">` has text `[mytext]`, that mean `[ ]` symbol is important.

How to do this by JS/Jquery ?

Comment: how many `.thisdiv` will be there?

Comment: One `.thisdiv` will be there :-)

Comment: _if another div .textdiv has_ What do you mean by this?

Comment: i mean, add class to `.thisdiv` if only `<div class="textdiv">` has text `[mytext]`, that mean `[ ]` symbol is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use contains() in the selector, but that is not going to be an exact match, it can match a partial text in the element. aka "foo" would match "foo" or "food"

```js
//$('.textdiv:contains("\[mytext\]")').addClass("mytext");
if($('.textdiv:contains("\[mytext\]")').length) {
    $(".thisdiv").addClass("mytext");
}
```

```css
.mytext { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="textdiv">
  <div class="here">
  [mytext]
 </div>
</div>
<div class="thisdiv">FOO</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not like this, I mean, add class to `.thisdiv` if only `<div class="textdiv">` has text `[mytext]`, that mean [ ] symbol is important and replace text to class is important.

Comment: So is it hard to replace my foobar with `[mytext]`? I made the change. Now if the text inside of the brackets is variable, than it requires more code and you might want to state that in your question.

Comment: But, `addClass("mytext");` where? It should be add class to `<div class="thisdiv">` only. I mean i want to add class only to `<div class="thisdiv">`

Comment: So I made the change. I used an if to see if the element contains the text. If it finds one, it ads the class to some other element.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly.

```
function addTextClass(text,tclass){
  if(typeof text == "undefined") return;
  if(typeof tclass == "undefined") tclass=text; //Set class to the same as text if class is not specified.
  $('.textdiv').each(function(){
   if($(this).html().indexOf(text) > 0 )
      $('.thisdiv').addClass(class);
  });
}
```

You would call it like:

```
addTextClass('mytext');
```

or

```
addTextClass('MyText','MyClass');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3fyxdjk3/3/

Comment: Thanks, Please provide JSfiddle example.